# how can i calculate vacation accumulation base on hiredate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need calculate the total vacation hours each employee take again  their hiredate. It is easy to get one employee

```
SELECT      PRCo, Employee,  SUM(dbo.PRTH.Hours) AS TotalHrs, 
                         dbo.PREH.HireDate
FROM        A    
WHERE       A.ActiveYN = 'Y') AND (A.EarnCode IN (5249, 5257, 5258, 5279, 5286, 5296, 5309, 7711, 7733)) AND (A. PostDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-15 00:00:00', 102)) AND (A.PostDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-08-21 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY A.PRCo, A.Employee, A.PREH.HireDate
HAVING        (A.Employee = 1)
```

I have a hard time to get all the employee since post date range are different from each other base on the Hiredate. . I am thinking use cursor or  loop  but I am sure how exactly it works or it will work. Any suggestion will preciate.  I use t-sql. Thanks

Comment: How do you find the post dates for a given employee?

Comment: if post_date is saved in any table then you can modify the sql query. Please also share the structure of table where hours,hiredate are saved and also the table structure where post date are saved.

Comment: Can you fix your code to be more coherent?

Comment: Postdate is just the acutly day employee take vacation. For example is a employee hiredate is 08/21/2010, the post date range will be 8/21/2012 till today 07/16/2013. So i need calculate total hours this employee take during the postdate range. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table with the Employee_Id and Post_Date values. In the main query join this temp table with the employee id and fetch the post date values. Here is a sample query:

SELECT
    PRCo, Employee,  SUM(dbo.PRTH.Hours) AS TotalHrs, dbo.PREH.HireDate

FROM
    A
JOIN
    #TEMP B
ON
    A.Employee=B.Employee_Id
WHERE
    A.ActiveYN = 'Y') AND 
    (A.EarnCode IN (5249, 5257, 5258, 5279, 5286, 5296, 5309, 7711, 7733)) 
    AND (A. PostDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, B.Post_Date, 102)) 
    AND (A.PostDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, B.Post_Date, 102))
GROUP BY 
    A.PRCo, A.Employee, A.PREH.HireDate
HAVING
    (A.Employee = 1)

Comment: Thanks. I still a little confused. For employee 1 i need select postdate from 8/21/2012 -- today. But for empoyee 2 i need select postdate from 5/7/2012 ---today.  then sum the total hours during these range.

Comment: Create a temporary table with two columns called Employee_ID and postdate. Insert values for these columns, for example Employee_1 and 8/21/2012, Employee_2 and 5/7/2012 etc. Then join this temp table as mentioned in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code would help:

CREATE TABLE #TEMP(EMPLOYEE_ID INT, POST_DATE DATETIME, HOURS INT)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1,'8/21/2012',DATEDIFF(HH,'8/21/2012',GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2,'5/7/2012',DATEDIFF(HH,'8/21/2012',GETDATE()))
SELECT
    PRCo, Employee,  SUM(dbo.PRTH.Hours) AS TotalHrs, dbo.PREH.HireDate

FROM
    A
JOIN
    #TEMP B
ON
    A.Employee=B.Employee_Id
WHERE
    A.ActiveYN = 'Y') AND 
    (A.EarnCode IN (5249, 5257, 5258, 5279, 5286, 5296, 5309, 7711, 7733)) 
    AND (A. PostDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, B.Post_Date, 102)) 
    AND (A.PostDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, B.Post_Date, 102))
GROUP BY 
    A.PRCo, A.Employee, A.PREH.HireDate
HAVING
    (A.Employee = 1)